# Vue Warn: property "search" is not defined on instance

Tags: django, vue.js, django-rest-framework, vuetify.js, nuxt.js

i'm creating a web app with a Django server with api from rest_framework and Vue as frontend (Nuxtjs in particular).

Trying to create a "search filter bar" i've got this error and i don't know why:

> ERROR  [Vue warn]: Property or method "search" is not defined on the instance but
> referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive,
> either in the data option, or for class-based components, by
> initializing the property. See:
> https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Declaring-Reactive-Properties.

This is my file.vue

```
<template>
    <div>
      <v-text-field v-model="search" label="search conditions" outlined dense></v-text-field>
    </div>
    <div>
      <v-list v-for="condition in filteredConditions" :key="condition.id" >
          <v-list-item>
            <condition-card :onDelete="deleteCondition" :condition="condition"></condition-card>
          </v-list-item>
      </v-list>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>


<script>
  import ConditionCard from "~/components/ConditionCard.vue";
 export default {
  head() {
    return {
      title: "Conditions list",
      search: ""
    };
  },
  components: {
    ConditionCard
  },
  async asyncData({ $axios, params }) {
    try {
      let query = await $axios.$get(`/conditions/`);
      if (query.count > 0){
          return { conditions: query.results }
      }
      return { conditions: [] };
    } catch (e) {
      return { conditions: [] };
    }
  },
  data() {
    return {
      conditions: []
    };
  },
  ...
  ...
 computed: {
  filteredConditions: function(){
    return this.conditions.filter((condition) => {
      return condition.name.toLowerCase().match(this.search.toLocaleLowerCase())
    });
  }
 }

};
</script>


<style scoped>
</style>
```

The api is:

```
{"count":15,
 "next":null,
 "previous":null,
 "results":[{"id":1,
             "name":"Blinded",
             "description":"A blinded creature can't see...",
             "source_page_number":290}, 
             {"id":2,
              "name":"Charmed",
              "description":"A charmed creature can't...",
              ...
              ...
```

Comment: Maybe you mean to have search inside data object?

Comment: Exactly, moving search: '' inside data object, the program works. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to move the `search` variable from `head()` to `data()`

```
head() {
    return {
        title: "Conditions list"
    }
},
...
data(){
    return{
        conditions: [],
        search : ''
    }
}
```